# What are some Japanese euphemisms for death and dying?

Tags: words, expressions, colloquial-language

Could you list some euphemisms on death and dying used by Japanese people in everyday speech? I'm writing a paper on Japanese language euphemisms and would like to know more about expressions used by native speakers (not enough time to do a full survey, unfortunately). Would appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you attempted to research this topic or look for any yourself?  If so, I would edit your question to reflect that.  Otherwise it will probably be closed as a translation request which is [off-topic](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/799/29).